# Is Nonmetallic Sheathed Cable Safe to Touch?

Tags: electrical, attic

I just went up into my attic and as expected there are a bunch of electrical cables up there and it just occurred to me that no one has ever directly told me that it was safe to touch a nonmetallic sheathed cable (Romex) before. So that's my question, is it safe to touch a live insulated cable in your attic?

I am well aware that it is a terrible idea to touch a live bare copper wire.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to touch the insulating jacket of an undamaged NM cable.

However, in the state of California, it may cause cancer to lick the cables.

Comment: If you're in the state of California, you are either already dead, or immune to cancer.

Comment: Note that this only applies for *undamaged* cable. If the cable has been torn, punctured, worn through while pulling, or cracked from age, the insulation might not be as good as when new. Bonus points if wet.